# Why not autostart PPP?

Tags: adb, linux

In the adb docs, under PPP it says "Note that you should not automatically start a PPP connection."

Anybody know why this is discouraged? I'd like to do exactly that when I plug my tablet into my computer. I've got a script to launch adb ppp and a x11vnc server to use the tablet as a second screen over USB, and I'd like to use udev to set it up automatically.